# JFrame appears blank then JComponents appear after a few seconds. How do I stop this?

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to learn Java Swing, and I've been reading and watching tutorials. Something that keeps happening to me is that I will play my program, and the JFrame will be blank for a few seconds then my buttons, labels, panels, etc. will be added. Sometimes, it is instant. I don't know why it's happening. It seems like it is related to the layout. For instance, this code makes my components appear instantly:

```
import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Buttons {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.PINK);
        panel.setBounds(0, 0, 250, 250);

        JButton button = new JButton("Bruno");
        button.addActionListener(e -> System.out.println("Bruno"));
        
        panel.add(button);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

However, when I change the layout of the panel in the following code, my components do not show up for a few seconds:

```
import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Buttons {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.PINK);
        panel.setBounds(0, 0, 250, 250);
        panel.setLayout(null);

        JButton button = new JButton("Bruno");
        button.setBounds(75, 75, 100, 100);
        button.addActionListener(e -> System.out.println("Bruno"));
        
        panel.add(button);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Any help with why this is happening would be appreciated.

When I switch my layouts of the panel or even the frame, it changes. Sometimes my components appear as I want them, but sometimes it takes a few seconds for them to appear (after a blank JFrame appears). I'm very new to Java Swing, so is there something that I'm missing when it comes to displaying the JFrame?

Comment: You're missing Swing layout managers.  Null layouts lead to nothing but trouble.  Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay particular attention to the [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) section.

Comment: Construct and manipulate Swing GUI objects _only_ on the [event dispatch thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Comment: `frame.setLayout(null);` isn't helping you, but the "delay" isn't really something you can get rid of, it's a side effect of the underlying system spinning up

Comment: Using null layouts is a recipe for disaster. It may seem to a newbie the easier way to create a GUI, but it leads to creation of rigid, hard to debug, enhance and change GUI's and it fights against the way that the Swing library is built to be used. For your benefit and ours, best to learn about the layout managers and then use them. Note that you can (and should) nest JPanels, each that use its own layout manager.